# Reversing Yes/No field during Select in Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, data-migration

Is there a way to reverse a Yes/No field during a select statement in Access?  I know how to do so during SQL but that does not fly in Access.

Here is the scenario:

I'm migrating data from an Access DB to an SQL DB.  A Yes/No field in said data in Access is obsolete_flag.  In SQL correspondingly, I have IsActive.  The value needs reversed for SQL since IsActive implies it to be true whereas obsolete_flag would show it is false.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Kindest Regards,
Chad Johnson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the easiest way would be to just add 1 to the value. This will reverse the yes/no field and make it compatible at the same time.

```
SELECT obsolete_flat+1 AS IsActive
```

This will change Access False values (0) to SQLServer True (1), and Access True values (-1) to SQLServer False (0).

You guys were just over thinking it.

Comment: No go on this solution also. When data comes back from Access for Yes/No, it comes as "true", "false". Try adding + 1 to that and you get the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'False' to data type int."

I think for now I'll stick with my foreach loop since it seems to be the only thing correctly reversing the data values.

Comment: That solution will work in Access. However, your error tells me that you already converted the table to SqlServer, so you need a solution that works in SS. OK, try this:
`UPDATE test SET isactive = CASE WHEN obsolete_flat = 'True' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: My bad on that one.  I thought you meant once it came over to SQL.  I made the fix and it appears to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes/No is a bit, you can use
`SELECT NOT obsolete_flat AS IsActive` .....

What about

`SELECT CASE WHEN obsolete_flag = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsActive` ...

Comment: This worked in Access but leaves it unreadable to SQL.  Reason being, Access changes Yes values to -1, No values to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I came up with my own solution.  I just foreach looped the Access data and reversed the value of the obsolete_flag before I insert it into SQL.  Not elegant but works I guess.  If anyone has a way to do it better in SQL or Access, let me know and I'll give you credit.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, whatever works for you, I guess. But please try not to call SQL Server simply "SQL". *SQL* is a *language* and *SQL Server* is a *product*, one of the many that use SQL. I realise that in some situations (e.g. among your colleagues) it may be perfectly fine (or, rather, it's up to you) to call SQL Server, "SQL", but generally that's just incorrect and may be very confusing. In large communities it's a good idea to stick to correct terms to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Your comment has little meaning in this situation.  In the tags, it clearly has SQL Server 2008.  Try reading before attempting to lecture/critique, especially since you didn't even attempt to provide any sort of answer to the original question.  Not meaning to come off as an ass but seriously, why bother to critique if you're not even going to do anything meaningful with your post to begin with.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you. I only meant to ask you to be less ambiguous in your posts, that's all. I did read both your question and your answer. In fact, it was after I read them and finally realised what you meant by "SQL" that I decided to post my comment. Again, I didn't mean to offend you by it and I'm really sorry if I did.

Comment: Not so much as offended as it irked me that you bothered to critique vs. answer the question.  What was the point?  If someone asks a question, people generally would like suggestions on how to solve their problem, not to be lectured about how they asked their question, which has nothing to do with the actual question.  Yes, I could have said "in SQL Server, how do I blah blah."  I was wanting the actual SQL statements to make this happen.  The actual SQL wouldn't be that different from what I've seen in research prior to post.  Anyways, keep that in mind before you would supply an answer.

Comment: You mean, the point behind my asking you to be clearer? The clearer your question is, the less time a person needs to comprehend it, the more chance, therefore, they are going to invest *more* of their time to try and answer it. Believe me, when I was posting my comment, I had *your* interests in mind just as well as those of the community at large. I wasn't attacking you. Instead, I was trying to make my suggestion in an as friendly way as possible. Apparently, I failed big time. Nevertheless, I'm still convinced that you might benefit from being less ambiguous when asking your questions.

Comment: *sighs* Alright, I'm going to make this as clear as possible since my words are obviously not reaching you.  Two other people posted answers to my question, both suggesting helpful ideas, with one even being the answer I needed.  Then there was your comment criticizing me over the ambiguous usage of the word SQL, and to end it, you left no answer.  Instead of lecturing, how about asking me to _clarify_ my _question_?  Btw, of the three people that responded to my post, the two that left me an _actual answer_ were helpful to me.  Does that make it _clear enough_?

Comment: No, it was never lost on me that, while I was "lecturing" you, others were answering your question. I never said that your being unclear/ambiguous *prevents* (or *can* prevent) you from getting answers. My point was merely, that your being *clearer* gets you more chances to get an answer. In the end, it boils down to how happy you are with the pace and quality of the answers you get. You do seem to be happy with that, and I'm sincerely happy for you too.

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem to you obtuse by apparently not addressing all of your points in my replies. That's partly because I'm trying to focus more on explaining my motives behind my writing the original comment, for, as you have clearly shown, it seems to have made a rather heavy impression on you. I never wanted to be pushy and I didn't really mean to criticise. You, however, keep calling it a "criticism" even after I explained that I meant it as a friendly suggestion. Maybe the problem is that you don't believe I acted in good will letting you know that your question contained a confusion.